# Canceling Fade Out Effect On A Tooltip Hover

Tags: jquery

I need a tooltip with hyperlinks inside for a web site. I wrote the code below and seems that it is working fine, expect one problem, once I hover the tooltip block it fades out and then fades in. I need to prevent fadeout when I hovet on it somehow. I tried to use the stop() method but it did not work, most probably I did something wrong :) Could you please help. Thanks.

HTML

```
<div id="hover">
    <div class="tooltip">

        <a href="#"></a>
        <a href="#"></a>
        <a href="#"></a>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#hover {
    position: relative;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background: green;
}
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    width: 45px;
    top: 80px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
     padding: 5px;
}
a{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: red;
}
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tooltip").hide();

    $("#hover").hover(function(){
        $(this).find(".tooltip").fadeIn();
        },function(){
        $(this).find(".tooltip").delay(1000).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

The demo is here http://jsfiddle.net/8gC3D/2904/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **.stop()** to clear the animation queue.

> When .stop() is called on an element, the currently-running animation
>   (if any) is immediately stopped.

1. You need to remove the **delay(1000)** applied in the second
   function passed to the **hover()** method.
2. Also make sure to add the **stop()** method to stop any current
       animation if you hover out quickly and clear the queue.

   ```
   $("#hover").hover(function(){
       $(this).find(".tooltip").stop().fadeIn();
       },function(){
       $(this).find(".tooltip").stop().fadeOut();
   });
   ```

Make sure to wrap it all in a document ready function.

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/8gC3D/2905/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tooltip").hide();
    
    $("#hover").hover(function(){
        $(this).find(".tooltip").stop().fadeIn();
        },function(){
        $(this).find(".tooltip").stop().fadeOut();
    });
});
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#hover {
    position: relative;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background: green;
}
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    width: 45px;
    top: 80px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
     padding: 5px;
}
a{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
 border: 1px solid black;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hover">
    <div class="tooltip">
  
        <a href="#"></a>
        <a href="#"></a>
        <a href="#"></a>
  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works with the way you described, I just wanted to ask if there is a way do delay the fadeout if user is not so quick :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably the problem is in the animation queue of jQuery try to use [`.stop` method](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) to clear the previous queue like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $(".tooltip").hide();

$("#hover").hover(function(){
    $(this).find(".tooltip").stop().fadeIn();
    },function(){
    $(this).find(".tooltip").stop().delay(1000).fadeOut();
});

});
```

1. https://api.jquery.com/stop/
2. https://css-tricks.com/examples/jQueryStop/

Comment: thanks for you answer, however it works only if I remove the delay method. so the next answer did the work. but thanks anyway :)

Comment: @EmilGurbanov, ok i was not sure of the reason the `.delay` was there so i left it, the answer is illustrative, cheers